# Prove that the sum of derivatives of a non-negative function is non-negative

Tags: derivatives, polynomials

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ with real coefficients such that $f(x)$ is non-negative for all real $x$. Let $g(x)=f(x)+f'(x)+f''(x)+\dots$ be the sum of $f(x)$ and the first $n$ derivatives of $f(x)$. Show that $g(x)$ is non-negative for all real $x$.

Thanks for any comments/answers in advance!

Comment: $$
g(x) = e^x\left[\int_x^\infty f(t)e^{-t}\;dt\right] > 0 .
$$

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks a lot for the insightful comment!

Comment: But could you please elaborate on how you get this equality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $f(x) $ must have even degree and a positive leading coefficient (unless it is zero, in which case it's trivial) and thus so must $g(x)$. Thus, $g$ has a global minimum, say at $y$. From the definition of $g$, $g'(y)=0$ then implies that $g(y) = f(y) \ge 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear explanation!